# How to spy date with jasmine-node

Tags: node.js, jasmine

As per the example given in official [documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_Date),

```
describe("Mocking the Date object", function(){
    it("mocks the Date object and sets it to a given time", function() {
      var baseTime = new Date(2013, 9, 23);

      jasmine.clock().mockDate(baseTime);
      :
    });
  });
```

It reports `jasmine.clock is not a function`. I'm using following dependencies in my project

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^2.5.2",
    "jasmine-node": "^1.14.5"
  }
```

I also tried to mock Date object. But since I'm in node not on browser, I don't find/get `window` to mock any method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was using unofficial jasmine library. So I should have used "jasmine-core" instead of "jasmine-node" to get support of latest jasmine release. However it still was failing to mock dates.

So I separated a function to return date. then;

1. I exported the function so it can be mocked. I used jasmine's `spyOn` to mock the behaviour of date function.
2. I found a npm library `rewire` which helps to access private variable or methods of a nodejs module. So it can also be used to `spyOn` date function instead of exporting it just because of mocking.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install [jasmine-mockdate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-mockdate). 
Then test as follow:

```
describe("Mocking the Date object", function () {
    it("mocks the Date object and sets it to a given time", function () {
        var baseTime = new Date(2013, 9, 23);
        jasmine.clock().install();
        jasmine.clock().mockDate(baseTime);

        jasmine.clock().tick(50);
        expect(new Date().getTime()).toEqual(baseTime.getTime() + 50);        
    });
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: The linked npm package states (emphasis mine): "Mock Date for Jasmine v1.3. _For v2.x, use jasmine.clock().mockDate() instead._"

Comment: As I stated jasmine version in question, I'm expecting `jasmine.clock()` should be available.